# How to add 2 hours in current time - Date time picker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I need to know about add 2 hours in current time. I am using Responsive datetime picker jQuery plugin. I want if anyone select today's date the current time shows with adding 2 hours in it. Now it shows current time after select today's date.

**Date picker jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.noConflict(); (function($){  
  $(function(){
    var dateToday = new Date();
    var dates = $("#pickupdate").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: false,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      minDate: dateToday,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);             }       
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**Time Picker jQuery.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.noConflict();
  (function($) {
    $(function(){
      $("#dtBox").DateTimePicker({
        mode: 'time',
        timeFormat: "hh:mm AA",
        isPopup: false, 
        addEventHandlers: function(){
          var oDTP = this;
          oDTP.settings.minTime = oDTP.getDateTimeStringInFormat("Time", "hh:mm AA", new Date());
          oDTP.settings.maxTime = "06:00 PM";
        }
      });
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: anyone please help me .

Comment: can anyone review and help me.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a jsfiddle.net example of your code and what you have tried.

Comment: i just want if someone select today's date the current time add 2 hours in and display but if someone select tomorrow's date, time will be start from 09 AM. I have set maximum time to 06:00 Pm in both cases.